# QAbstractTableModel updating background color

Tags: qt

I have a table with 3 columns: {"Scanned","Qty", "Item"}. I am trying to highlight the particular row if the "Scanned" and "Qty" column value matches. I saw some posts which says to implement it in the following

> data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const

I have tried as follow to just change the background color of the table rows regardless but it does not seem to work as suggested:

```
QVariant TransitItemTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    switch (role) {
    case TableDataRow:
    {
        return table.at(index.row()).at(index.column());
    }
    case HeadingRow:
    {
        if (index.row() == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    case Qt::BackgroundRole:
    {
        QBrush redBackground(Qt::green);
        return redBackground;

    }
    default:
        break;
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

I am calling

> emit dataChanged
>   in the following code below:

```
bool TransitItemTableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,
                               int role)  {
    if (!index.isValid() || 
            index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= table.size())
        return false;

    QList<QString> list1 = value.value<QList<QString>>();
    QVector<QString> list2 = list1.toVector();

    table.replace(index.row(), list2);
    emit dataChanged(index, index, {TableDataRow});
    return true;
}
```

Just for additional info, I have the following roles defined:

```
enum TableRoles {
        TableDataRow = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        HeadingRow
    };
```

With regards to the QML code, I am using the following code for display as Table.qml and the lower portion of code shows part of the code using this Table.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

TableView {
    id: root
    anchors.fill: parent
    clip: true
    signal clicked(int row, int column)
    property var columnWidths: [0.5, 0.5]   // as fractions of parent width
                                            // preferably overwrite this when using
    columnWidthProvider: function (column) { return Math.max(parent.width * columnWidths[column], 1) }

    delegate: Rectangle {
        implicitHeight: text.implicitHeight
        border.color: "#dddddd"
        color: (heading==true)?"#dddddd":"white"
        Text {
            id: text
            text: tabledata
            width: parent.width
            wrapMode: Text.Wrap
            padding: 5
        }
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: root.clicked(model.row, model.column)
        }
    }
}
```

```
Rectangle {
      color: "transparent"
      Layout.fillWidth: true
      Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height - 250

      Components.Table {
          model: _transitItemTableModelAPI
          columnWidths: [0.2, 0.15, 0.65]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test the validity of your index:

```
if (index.isValid())
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        return QString("hello data");
    }
    else if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole)
    {
        return QColor(Qt::lightGray);
    }
}
```

Other than that, your code should work fine. Can you see your data values? You shouldn't, as you are not returning data in case role is Qt::DisplayRole.
Are you sure, you hooked your model to your QTableView with `setModel();`

**EDIT**: From the doc:

> The optional roles argument can be used to specify which data roles
>   have actually been modified. An empty vector in the roles argument
>   means that all roles should be considered modified. The order of
>   elements in the roles argument does not have any relevance.

`emit dataChanged(index, index, {TableDataRow});` will not update the BackgroundRole.

Comment: currently it can display the data values, i have added the code on setData

Comment: hm how should i go about if i need to keep the custom TableDataRow?

Comment: emitData gets a QVector<int> as third argument. Put your custom role and BachgroundRole into this vector.